# Android google maps v2 show gray tiles

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using google maps v2 for android in my app.
I have a strange problem
I'm using the same xml for two activities, so i have two java files that uses setContentView with the same layout file.

In this xml there is a mapfragment, in one activity everything works fine, but in the other acitivy the mapfragment only shows gray tiles with the google logo in the lower right corner, which could be the reason?

I use the same code to set up the map.

The javas are in two different subpackages like:

mypackage.home
mypackage.factories

can anyone help me?

Comment: why you want to bind a single xml to two different activity, just make a clone of the one you have and then bind it to your second activity for which you are facing problem.

Comment: I am with the same problem. Have you already solved this?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem. I had the same set of codes for the most part, but my second map was just displaying gray tiles.

It turns out I forgot to include this code:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myMapView.onResume();
    }
```